# build in numpy function to get index from an array randomly

Tags: python, numpy

Is there build in numpy funciton to return index `idx` from one dimensional array `r` with probability `r[i]`. All `r[i]` non negative and sums to one.

Answer (score 1):

Almost built in:

```
# setup (do this once)
cs = r.cumsum()

# get a random value with probability r[i]
rn = np.random.uniform()
idx = cs.searchsorted(rn)
```

Answer (score 0):

[scipy.stats](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html) can help, even if it is not in NumPy as requested:

```
import scipy.stats
r = [.1,.8,.1]
x = range(len(r))
mydist = scipy.stats.rv_discrete(values=(x,r), name='mydist')
print mydist.rvs(size=20)
# array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```